# Problem to use Microsoft Graph Delta query for Event Syncing

Tags: python, python-3.x, office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm developing an in-house application. This will be used to backup and sync our Office 365 Calendar and Events data locally. 
To implement differential sync as per Graph API documentation, the Delta Query is the best option to go for. While implementing this Delta Query for '/CalendarView' two parameters are mandatory(startDateTime, endDateTime). These two parameters actually set the range of the events to track for any changes. I have check this maximum range and found the range can be 100 years.
Our application does have a longer range than this as we have historical Calendars maintained.

I have already considered the below solutions:

Sol #1: /events with $filter query using lastModifiedDateTime gt 'last backup' time.

> This solution doesn't return the deleted events data

Sol #2: /calendarView/delta?startDateTime = ''&endDateTime =''

> This solution have a limited range of 100 years.

Tried
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{user_id}}/events?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime gt '2019-06-26T02:56:41.828Z'

Tried
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{user_id}}/calendar/calendarView/delta?startDateTime=1989-06-20T02:56:41.828Z&endDateTime=2088-06-26T02:56:41.828Z

Find out a solution to implement differential sync for no such range or a different approach for the said problem.